# Populating a SelectList from a Database

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, webforms

I am completely new to using JSON data and ajax but I have a Select List I want populated from a web service. I have used fiddler to see that the web service is returning JSON data correctly and I verified that it is. The selectlist is only displaying the default `----Select-----`

The code for the web service:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ToolboxItem(false)]

 [ScriptService]
public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    private TrackerEntities db = new TrackerEntities();


    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string GetCompanies()
    {
        var companies = new List<Company>();
        companies = (from c in db.Ref_Company
                     select new Company { CompanyDesc =  c.CompanyDesc,CompanyCode = c.CompanyCode }).ToList();
        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(companies);
    }


}

public class Company
{
    public string CompanyCode { get; set; }
    public string CompanyDesc { get; set; }
}
```

The Code for the HTML

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         data: "{}",
         url: "WebService1.asmx/GetCompanies",
         dataType: "json",
         success: ajaxSucceess,
         error: ajaxError
     });
     function ajaxSucceess(data) {
        $.each(data, function (index, elem) {
           // Create a new <option>, set its text and value, and append it to the <select>
           $("<option />")
              .text(elem.CompanyCode)
              .val(elem.CompanyDesc)
              .appendTo("#Select1");
        });
     }

     function ajaxError(response) {
         alert(response.status + ' ' + response.statusText);
     }
 });


</script>   
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">


 <select id="Select1"><option>---Select------</option></select>


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is `ajaxSuccess()` being called?  Does it iterate over the returned values?  When you debug this, at what point does it fail?

Comment: It fails when at what seems to be at the ajaxSuccess function, It is adding a blank record under the ---Select----. Sorry I'm pretty new to ajax

Comment: You can debug your JavaScript code in browser debugging tools, such as Firebug or Chrome developer tools.  When you say it fails at the `ajaxError` function, what indication do you have of this failure?  Do you mean that the `alert()` in that function is executing?  If the AJAX call itself is failing then you'll want to check your browser debugging tools to determine the response coming back from the server.  That response may contain a useful error message or some other indication of a server-side failure unrelated to the JavaScript code.

Comment: On firebug it looks like it is going through the error step

Comment: If the server is returning an error in the AJAX call then something is failing in server-side code.  You'll need to debug the server-side code and determine what that is.  There's most likely an error message being generated somewhere, you're just not looking at it.

Comment: My mistake, it is going through the success step, so it doesn't seem like it is iterating through the data

Comment: What's the actual value of `data` in the success function?  Are you able to loop through it with a normal `for` loop?

Comment: I'm not sure how to see the values of `data` but it says in firebug that it is an array of 0 elements

Comment: If it's an array of 0 elements then the server isn't returning any data from your query.  In that case the code is behaving correctly.  You're just not seeing anything added to the HTML because there are no records to add.

Comment: It is does show the service being called and all the elements in JSON though

Comment: There's a conflict between "it is an array of 0 elements" and "all the elements in JSON."  Can you include in the question the actual JSON response being returned by the service?  Perhaps it's malformed?  Also, instead of calling `$.each()` on the JSON array, what happens if you just use a normal `for` loop?

Comment: `{"d":"[{\"CompanyCode\":\"HTH\",\"CompanyDesc\":\"Company1\"},{\"CompanyCode\":\"SMC\",\"CompanyDesc\":\"Company2\"},{\"CompanyCode\":\"CTT\",\"CompanyDesc\":\"Company3\"}]"}`. A normal for loop is returning the same empty array

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments above, I think the issue is that you're not accessing the array properly.  Considering this JSON response:

```
{ "d" : "[
  { "CompanyCode" : "HTH", "CompanyDesc" : "Company1" },
  { "CompanyCode" :‌ "SMC", "CompanyDesc" : "Company2" },
  { "CompanyCode" : "CTT", "CompanyDesc" : "‌​Company3" }
]"}
```

If this is the value of `data` in your success function in the JavaScript code, then you can't loop through `data` as an array.  Because `data` isn't an array, it's a single object.  That object *contains* an array, in a property called `d`.  Try changing your call to `$.each()` to use that property instead:

```
$.each(data.d, function (index, elem) {
    //...
});
```

You might even test it with a normal `for` loop to make sure:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
    // do something with data.d[i]
}
```